# Using PCA before Bayes classificition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying using PCA before bayes classification ,but it says Native Bayes requires nonnegative features values, the training data used is nonnegative, but it turns to negative using PCA, how do I fix it ,Thanks to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the dimension of your inputs, you can use nonnegative matrix factorization instead. In Spark, this method is in `mllib.recommendation.ALS` and then set the nonnegative parameter as `True`.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to using NMF, but I can't find it in spark before, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you ever using ALS to reduce the dimension of inputs for Native-Bayes Classification?

Comment: @LiYu, I haven't but what I know is that one underlying assumption for Naive Bayes Classification is strong independence in the features. In the case of the NMF implemented in Spark, it does not consider orthogonality when it factorizes the original matrix so it might not work really well for your application.